# NGinx / PHP 404 Not Found when redirecting away from main website

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I got my main website running but a click on any button on the website leads to a 404 Error. The buttons show that it is looking for an actual page (such as /signin or /signup) in the public directory but there is only the index.php. Any idea why? I pasted the nginx cfg and error log below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    root /root/var/www/myforum/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Error log when clicking on the Sign In button on my website:

> 2021/12/10 01:54:34 [error] 53165#53165: *333 open() "/root/var/www/myforum/public/signin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 1xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), request: "GET /signin HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xxx.xxx.1xx", referrer: "http://xx.xxx.xxx.1xx/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was the second /root/ as well as a missing

```
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```